# Is Binary Integer Linear Programming solvable in polynomial time?

Tags: computational-complexity, linear-programming, integer-programming

The paper [Solving the Binary Linear Programming Model in Polynomial Time](http://www.scirp.org/journal/paperinformation.aspx?paperid=62642) claims that Binary Integer Linear Programming is in P. However, it seems that no subsequent literature in the mainstream has done any further study on this. I am a bit doubtful regarding the correctness of the claim made in that paper. 
Therefore, I have put this question here.

Answer (score 7):

Often called Binary Integer Programming (BIP).
[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming):

> Integer programming is NP-complete. In particular, the special case of 0-1 integer linear programming, in which unknowns are binary, and only the restrictions must be satisfied, is one of Karp's 21 NP-complete problems.

[Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karp%27s_21_NP-complete_problems) is a list of those 21 Karp problems.

You can also find the claim that BIP $\in$ NPC in many class notes, e.g., 
[this set](http://www.mafy.lut.fi/study/DiscreteOpt/DOSLID3.pdf).

Comment: The cited paper actually acknowledges that BIP is NP-complete. In fact the paper explicitly claims to have proven that P = NP. That by itself is plenty reason to be "doubtful regarding the correctness of the claim" in the paper.

Comment: Thanks, @Joseph O'Rourke for your reply! However, I did check Wiki before posting the question. Please let me know if you are aware of any recent development on this.

Comment: The paper converts BIP to convex quadratic programming... whose minimization is solvable in polynomial time. but the author wants his readers to maximize a convex quadratic program which is very very hard. unless he came up with methods of maximizing convex quadratic program.